# Solr query wildcard problem, mismatch in results number vs real document count

Tags: solr, wildcard, alfresco

Ok, so the problem is that I get some crazy results using solr query from the admin console.

I try to search for some documents which have an alfresco property with a specific name.

The field name is "edm:uid"

So if I try to pass to "q" the following:

```
edm:uid:FULL_NAME_OF_THE_DOCUMENT
```

everything works perfectlly.

But if I try to use wildcards everythig breaks.

If I query for example "edm:uid:DOC_01_20190202*", I get let's say 5000 results, everything might be good. If I query "edm:uid:DOC_01*", I get around 1000 result, which I find crazy, as I remove from the matching, the resulting number should increase. If I query "edm:uid:DOC*" I get still around 1000 results, and I should have millions.

I really don't know how solr works, if anyone knows why this happens?
I tried several versions too and doesn't change the results, versions like:

edm:uid:"DOC*"
edm:uid:DOC*
edm:uid:"DOC*"

so tried to put quotes to value, or escape ":" or both didn't change anything.
Also, I found the schema with the fields, and that "edm:uid" is indexed and tokenized.
I also ticked the "debugQuery" option, but I don't understand anything there, just some scores.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the definition of the field you're searching? When you're using wildcards, analysis is not performed as you'd expect, and the text given is only matched against the generated tokens. If there is only a small subset of documents that have the token `DOC_01`, then those are the only ones returned. If your original query gets broken into `DOC`, `01` and `20190202`, then each of those tokens might produce a match, while `DOC_01*` will only match those that have that specific token. See my explanation from earlier today as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540445/

Comment: Solr uses fuzzy matching.

What happens when you do "=edm:uid:DOC_01_20190202*" with the equal sign?

Comment: Not much happens with "=". Based on what MatsLindh said I will try to change the type of that field to a type that doesn't get tokenized (more specifically from the current "alfrescoFieldType" to "alfrescoCollatableTextFieldType", which I notice the first one I cant use solr analyzer on it(error with no message), but second one works and return a full single word type). See if that solves the issue, I'll come back with info if it works or not. Thank you both for the help!

Comment: It's still behaving strangely. I changed the model, now that "edm:uid" field is of a different type which is not tokenized and does not support filters (TOKENIZED = FLASE; FACEATABLE = FALSE) but still bheave the same way...  I even tried the solr Analizer, and the result value is not tokenized, it's a single string ("word" type) so I dont get what's happening.